# Uncheck *Require user's permission* checkbox in ActiveDirectory

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I use the following script to create a user in active directory

```
Set objRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
strRoot = objRootLDAP.Get("DefaultNamingContext")
Set objContainer = GetObject("LDAP://OU=Users-New Profile,OU=Users,OU=company," & strRoot)
Set objNewUser = objContainer.Create("User", "cn=" & sSAMAccountName)
objNewUser.sAMAccountName = sSAMAccountName
objNewUser.SetInfo
objNewUser.userPrincipalName = sSAMAccountName & "@domain.com"
objNewUser.givenName = sFirstName
objNewUser.sn = sLastName
objNewUser.mail = sSAMAccountName & "@domain.com"
objNewUser.DisplayName = sFullName
objNewUser.homeDirectory = "\\server\users$\" & sSAMAccountName
objNewUser.homeDrive = "H:"
objNewUser.tsProfilePath = "\\server\users$\" & sSAMAccountName
objNewUser.tsHomeDirDrive = "H:"
objNewUser.AccountDisabled = False
objNewUser.SetPassword "Password"
objNewUser.pwdLastSet = CLng(0)
objNewUser.SetInfo
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to uncheck the *Require user's permission* checkbox on the Remote Control tab of the user properties window in ADUC. Any idea what property that is or how I can iterate through all the properties of a user object to find it?

[image]

Comment: You cannot manipulate windows with VBScript. You may want to have a look at AutoIt https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

Comment: I'm not really looking to manipulate the window. I'm looking to manipulate the data behind the window. I just posted a picture of the window as a reference to the property I want to modify. AutoIt is a good tool but for an entirely different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EnableRemoteControl` property on the new user:

```
objNewUser.EnableRemoteControl = 2
```

Set this to any of the following values:

> ```
> Disable                0  Remote control is disabled.
> EnableInputNotify      1  The user of remote control has full control of the user's session, with the user's permission.
> EnableInputNoNotify    2  The user of remote control has full control of the user's session; the user's permission is not required.
> EnableNoInputNotify    3  The user of remote control can view the session remotely, with the user's permission; the remote user cannot actively control the session.
> EnableNoInputNoNotify  4  The user of remote control can view the session remotely, but not actively control the session; the user's permission is not required.
> ```